# MSVC `type cast`: cannot convert from `Type` to `Type`

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile this:

```
typedef struct Type {
    int value;
} Type;


Type foobar(Type value) { return (Type)value; }
```

In MSVC2017, this throws the following error:

`C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'Type' to 'Type'`

This doesn't seem to happen if the filename ends in .cpp as opposed to .c. This also doesn't seem to happen with `gcc`. Why does this happen?

Comment: It's because it's a structure. Type casting can only be done on scalar types, unless casting to `(void)`.

Comment: Why does `gcc` allow this?

Comment: `gcc` will issue a warning if `-pedantic` is used: `warning: ISO C forbids casting nonscalar to the same type [-Wpedantic]`.

Comment: [onlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) accepts it. Perhps because no type conversion is necessary.

Comment: Why do you want to cast an object to something it already is? If you really want to do that, then you do so *via* a pointer: `return *((Type*)&value);` ... but much simpler is just `return value;`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm trying to compile [quickjspp](https://github.com/c-smile/quickjspp) in MSVC, but in several places, the original author type casts `JSValueConst` to a `JSValue` (it seems like they do this because in special builds, `JSValue` and `JSValueConst` are pointers).

Comment: @AdrianMole: You are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Type)value` violates the constraint in C 2018 6.5.4 2, which covers the cast operator:

> Unless the type name specifies a void type, the type name shall specify atomic, qualified, or unqualified scalar type,…

A scalar type is an arithmetic or pointer type, per C 2018 6.2.5 21:

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called *scalar types*. Array and structure types are collectively called aggregate types.

C++ has different rules and GCC, in its default mode, does not conform to the C standard in this respect.

There is no need for a cast here; in the `return` statement, `value` refers to the `value` parameter of the function, which has type `Type`. So `return value;` would suffice.

Comment: "GCC, in its default mode, does not conform to the C standard in this respect." Yes, it only conforms in the pedantic mode.